# OpenGL - Setting Built-in Uniform Variables

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have been reading through a bunch of tutorials and when I came across one about fog in OpenGL it mentioned the built in variable gl_FogParameters. Is this something that is set in the application and then accessible through the shader.

In other words, do you set the various fog variables up the same way:

```
glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, GL_LINEAR);
glFogf(GL_FOG_START, 10.f);
glFogf(GL_FOG_END, 40.f);
```

or is it actually a uniform you send to the shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the uniforms that start with `gl_` track some specific part of OpenGL's fixed-function state. They get their value from GL's fixed-function state. The specification states exactly which state maps to exactly which variables.

Comment: Also don't forget that fixed function is deprecated and hence those variables are not allowed for OpenGL-3 core profile or later.